# How to connect output layers to the input layer of another neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

The Actor-network has 5 input neurons representing the state values and will produce one output value held by one output neuron.

The Q Network has 6 input neurons: 5 representing the state values and 1 representing the output of Actor-network.

I'll do gradient descent to train the Actor-network seperately, holding Q network's weights as constant.

My question is:
How should I structure to plug the output layer of Actor-Network into the input layer of the Q network, with TensorFlow 2.x?

[image: Neural network structure]

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `ŧf.keras.Model` API:

```
actor_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=...,outputs=...)
Q_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=actor_model.outputs, outputs=...)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output of Actor-network is 1 single neuron, but the ideal input of the Q model will have 5 more neurons besides the 1 neuron output of Actor-network.

Comment: `inputs` and `outputs` can be `list`s of tensors, so you can just say, `tf.keras.Model(inputs=[actor_model.outputs, other_tensor1, other_tensor2,...]`. In the `Q_model` architecture, you can then just `tf.stack` the different neurons into a single `tf.Tensor`.